# How to use user defined keyboard shortcuts in Kate's terminal

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, kate

Recently I started using `Kate`. I find it a really beautiful and powerful editor. It is also very convenient that the user can type commands by using the embedded terminal.

One rather bizarre thing is that keyboard shortcuts cannot be applied. If for instance I have selected and copied a command, by typing `Ctrl+V` I cannot paste it. The default keyboard sequence is `Ctrl+Shift+V`.

It is really weird that `Kate` doesn't adopt terminal's shortcut, but instead it uses it's own.

Is there a way to modify this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is because Kate just uses an iframe (so to speak) to embed the terminal in it's window. In order to change the keyboard shortcuts you'll need to change them in the terminal app. I'm supposing that you use KDE?

Comment: @Seth: Actually I am not using KDE. I am using unity. In fact my terminal's shortcut's are `Ctrl+c` for copy and `Ctrl+v` for paste.

Comment: What do you use as your terminal emulator? gnome-terminal the default?

Comment: Ubuntu's default!

Comment: How do you turn this embedded terminal on? I'm trying to replicate this and I can't find that setting.

Comment: Try installing konsole. `sudo apt-get install konsole`

Comment: I installed Konsole...

Comment: I suppose you will be able to open kate's embedded konsole. http://imgur.com/8t11unF

Comment: That's just what I don't know how to do.. How do I open the embedded console? It doesn't open automatically.

Comment: You just press the terminal button on the bottom of the window. See the previous link

Comment: I had to enable the "terminal" plugin. Funny thing is it doesn't respond to changes in Konsole..

Comment: There is already a *Terminal tool view* plugin enabled but it's still not working... Could that be a bug?